# PHP/MySQL array replace function not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to replace all the text available in SQL table using array but I don't know how to accomplish it. I am successful to get all results but I am unable to use it in str_replace() function

Here is my Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [txtSearch] => fruits
            [txtReplace] => pizza
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [txtSearch] => vegetables
            [txtReplace] => beer
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [txtSearch] => fiber
            [txtReplace] => ice cream
        )

)
```

Here is my PHP Code

```
include('site-primary-config.php');
$select="SELECT txtSearch, txtReplace FROM tblreplacements";
$result = $conn->query($select) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);

$arr = array();
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr[] = $row;  
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';

$phrase  = "You should eat fruits, vegetables, and fiber every day.";
//$healthy = array("fruits", "vegetables", "fiber");
//$yummy   = array("pizza", "beer", "ice cream");
$newphrase = str_replace($arr['txtSearch'], $arr['txtReplace'], $phrase);
echo $phrase . "<br />" . $newphrase;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a mistake in your search and replace arrays. They need to be arrays of strings.

```
$arr = array('txtSearch' => array(), 'txtReplace' => array() );
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arr['txtSearch'][] = $row['txtSearch'];  
        $arr['txtReplace'][] = $row['txtReplace']; 
    }
}
```

and then :

```
$newphrase = str_replace($arr['txtSearch'], $arr['txtReplace'], $phrase);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your current code, you need to extract `txtSearch` and `txtReplace` into a single dimension:

```
$s = array_column($arr, 'txtSearch');
$r = array_column($arr, 'txtReplace');
$newphrase = str_replace($s, $r, $phrase);
```

Or use one array:

```
$x = array_column($arr, 'txtReplace', 'txtSearch');
$newphrase = str_replace(array_keys($x), $x, $phrase);
```

Or even better use `strtr()`:

```
$newphrase = strtr($phrase, array_column($arr, 'txtReplace', 'txtSearch'));
```